# Getting the location of rigid body object at current keyframe

Tags: python, animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I would like to print out the location of an object with this script:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
print(obj.location)
```

It prints it out correctly, but when I animate this object (it's a rigid body) and then at a particular keyframe I run this script again, it just prints out the same location.

I tried to set the frame with:

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(fr)
```

Like it is mentioned in these two questions:

- [How can I get the location of an object at each keyframe?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5636/how-can-i-get-the-location-of-an-object-at-each-keyframe)
- [Location of an object at a specific frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14809/location-of-an-object-at-a-specific-frame)

But the location just stays the same. How can I get the correct location of the cube?

Comment: i think this addon might help somebody.: [https://gum.co/TAsuA](https://gum.co/TAsuA) Find tutorial about this video: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSJU8VCNILU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSJU8VCNILU) [![Matrix World Data Addon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCJAR.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCJAR.jpg)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
print(obj.matrix_world.translation)
```

This gives you the location from object's matrix which changes each frame for rigid bodies

Comment: se the answer to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38466/after-setting-constraints-the-location-of-constrained-objects-bodies-is-not-acce for a slightly longer explanation of why this works.