# Setting/overriding context for rigid body bake

Tags: python, scripting, rigid-body-simulation, baking

I have a script that generates a tower of blocks, and I want to simulate this tower's collapse, tracking the position of each block as the tower collapses. (And then do this again and again for thousands of arbitrary towers.) I can do this for a given tower in the GUI by setting the current frame to some late frame, baking to the current frame, and then calling `object.matrix_world.translation` in the console to get a given object's location at the current frame. (If I don't bake first, then `object.matrix_world.translation` just gives me the initial location of each object.)

However, when I try to do this with scripting, `bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(bake=False)` gives me the error `Operator bpy.ops.ptcache.bake.poll() failed, context is incorrect`. The solution seems to be to "override the context" (e.g. [Setting the context for cloth bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/setting-the-context-for-cloth-bake)), but I couldn't figure out how to do that in my case (which should be even simpler, since I'm just doing a rigid body simulation).

Any idea how to make `bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(bake=False)` work?

(I included some background on what I'm trying to do in case there's a simpler way to get each rigid body's location at a given frame of the animation. This seemed relevant [ [Getting the location of rigid body object at current keyframe](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28031/getting-the-location-of-rigid-body-object-at-current-keyframe?rq=1) ] but, as I said earlier, if I don't bake first, then `object.matrix_world.translation` just gives me the initial location of each object, not its simulated location at the current frame.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(bake=False)` for Rigid Body doesn't work, because it needs the *point cache* and *scene* passed explicitly as context, so:

```
# override operator context
with bpy.context.temp_override(
    scene = bpy.context.scene,
    point_cache = bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache
):
    # bake to current frame under custom ops context
    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(bake=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. (I get a bunch of PyContext warnings now, but I guess that's the point.)

Comment: Could this answer be updated, now that this was deprecated and context.temp_override(...) and non-dictionary forms are the way forward?