# Setting constraints causes the location of the constrained objects/bodies not be accessible

Tags: python, scripting, constraints, coordinates

I set up 2 bodies manually & assigned *Copy Location* constraint to one with respect to another body. Then I set up the keyframe for the guiding body & then I started to view the change in the location of the constrained body. What I noticed in the 3D viewport was the constrained object moves, but when I look into its real position the values are stagnant. Why is that? I was unable to find my answer in previously asked questions by other people !!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by "stagnant". Did you try to change the offset and space parameters of the Copy Location constraint? What effect are you trying to create?

Comment: I added python & scripting because I want to access the values using the notation --> ob.location[1]

Comment: OK, maybe add some detail about that in your question, since the description doesn't mention it? And maybe try to add more info and images or a screen recording to demonstrate the problem. I at least couldn't understand precisely what the issue is from the description...

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28031/getting-the-location-of-rigid-body-object-at-current-keyframe (basically the same question and same answer, but more python-oriented)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object.location` will never give the "correct" position for a object that has a constraint on it (or a parented object).
That comes from the way [parenting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109/2217) and constraints mess with the global coordinates (their effect gets calculated after the `object.location`).

To get the world position of the a child object (or an object governed by a constraint) you should use `object.matrix_world.translation`.
[matrix_world](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world) returns a matrix for the object's transformations in world space. The `.translation` part will convert the matrix to a location vector (just like `.location`).

---

The [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Pepribal/Ref/Appendices/ParentInverse) has a good read for further explanation about the coordinates for parented objects (same principals for constraints).