# Get position of the camera in each frame of the animation

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I tried this code that I found in the net in order to print the location of the camera in each frame of the animation.

```
import bpy

camera=bpy.data.objects['Camera']
sce = bpy.context.scene

for f in range(sce.frame_start, sce.frame_end+1):
    sce.frame_set(f)
    print("Frame %i" % f)
    print(camera.location)
```

After execution I get a fix location while the animation is fine.

I get like this:

```
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 41
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 42
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 43
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 44
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 45
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 46
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 47
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 48
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 49
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>
Frame 50
<Vector (-35.4940, -2.9554, 5.3437)>`
```

How can I rectify the code ?

I have tried also the code given in this discussion :

[How can I get the location of an object at each keyframe?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5636/how-can-i-get-the-location-of-an-object-at-each-keyframe)

but it doesn't work. I get the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'action'
```

What is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: What is the desired output format of the position data that you want?

Comment: The code from @gandalf3's answer in the linked question works just fine

Comment: The code does not work fine, the camera moves but positions printed are the same!

Comment: I actually just tried your original code and it worked for me as well. Maybe you should post your blend file.

Comment: Is your camera object still named 'Camera'?

Comment: the reason is that you are using constraints not a real animation

Comment: @Chebhou what do you mean by real animation

Comment: @mariem not key-framed, the constraints does not change the real location rot.. they change the visual only

Comment: Yes, I replace the code by the following : obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['Camera']
    loc,rot,scale = obj.matrix_world.decompose()
and it is OK ! Thank you for you contribution